# dropdown com javascript puro

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

Fala galera, bom dia, to precisando de uma ajuda com um dropdown.
a cada doação no banco de dados eu tenho um botão que se clico aparece os itens que foram doados.

estou com a seguinte linha de código:

***user-donation.js***

```js
const dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow img');
for (dropdownBtn of dropdownBtns){
    dropdownBtn.onclick = dropDown;
}
function dropDown(){
    const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
    for (let content of contents){
        content.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

***user-donations.js***

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img src="{% static 'images/arrow-down-icon.png' %}" alt="" id="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="list-itens">
            {% for item in donation.items %}
            <li>{{item.material.name}} x{{item.quantity}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém quando eu clico em qualquer um dos `dropdownBtn` eu mostro os itens de todas as doações e não só a que eu quero.

Alguém será q consegue me ajudar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque um parâmetro na função `dropDown()` de onde você consegue saber a origem do clique.

```
function dropDown(e){...
                  ↑
```

Para saber qual elemento foi clicado e que chamou a função, você usa:

```
e.target
```

Com isso você consegue chegar ao elemento `.dropdown-content` próximo relacionado. Esse elemento é irmão do pai do botão clicado. Você chega nele com:

```
e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
              ↑             ↑
             pai   irmão adjacente do pai
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
const dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_img');
for (dropdownBtn of dropdownBtns){
    dropdownBtn.onclick = dropDown;
}
function dropDown(e){
   let alvo = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
   alvo.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content{
   display: none;
}
.show{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woothemesiconset/32/blue_arrow_down.png" alt="" class="arrow_img">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="list-itens">
            {% for item in donation.items %}
            <li>{{item.material.name}} x{{item.quantity}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woothemesiconset/32/blue_arrow_down.png" alt="" class="arrow_img">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="list-itens">
            {% for item in donation.items %}
            <li>{{item.material.name}} x{{item.quantity}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Nota:** nas imagens dos botões você está usando `id="arrow"`. Imagino que esses botões serão repetidos, logo irão repetir o mesmo
>   `id`, o que é incorreto. Um `id` deve ser único na página. Troque o
>   `id="arrow"` por `class="arrow_img"`.

Se quiser ocultar o que está aberto quando mostra outro, altere o código do `for` adicionando um `if` para remover a classe `.show` do que está aberto:

```js
const dropdownBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow_img');
for (dropdownBtn of dropdownBtns){
    dropdownBtn.onclick = dropDown;
}
function dropDown(e){

   let alvo = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

   const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
   for (let content of contents){
      if(alvo != content) content.classList.remove('show');
   }

   alvo.classList.toggle('show');

}
```

```css
.dropdown-content{
   display: none;
}
.show{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woothemesiconset/32/blue_arrow_down.png" alt="" class="arrow_img">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="list-itens">
            {% for item in donation.items %}
            <li>{{item.material.name}} x{{item.quantity}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="arrow">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woothemesiconset/32/blue_arrow_down.png" alt="" class="arrow_img">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <ul class="list-itens">
            {% for item in donation.items %}
            <li>{{item.material.name}} x{{item.quantity}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: o `id="arrow"` era pq eu estava tentando algo, mas depois percebi a incoerência, mas valeu por ter notado kkkkk, cara sua explicação foi simplesmente sensacional, consegui resolver o meu problema, muito obrigado.